# multiline label with fixed width

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In cocos2d for iPhone, how can I create a multiline label (textbox) with a fixed width?

Currently, I am using:

```
CCLabelTTF  *labelTextTop = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString: @"My long string that should be placed in two lines, instead of in one extremely long one."
                                        fontName:        @"Marker Felt" 
                                        fontSize:        40];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I currently use :

```
CGSize size;
size.width=400;
size.height=110;
sayBubbleTextDisplayed_=[[CCLabelTTF  labelWithString:@"some long and winded blabla "  
                                           dimensions:size 
                                            alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft 
                                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
                                             fontName:@"American Typewriter" 
                                             fontSize:16] retain];
```